# Telerik grid custom formatting changing displayed text colour If "Yes" green If "No" Red

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a simple grid which I want 4 columns to have set that if "Yes" is displayed then it's in green and if "No" is displayed then it's in red, these are the only 2 values which those columns can display

```
c.Bound(x => x.col1);
                    c.Bound(x => x.col2)
                        .Title("col2 example");
                    c.Bound(x => x.col3)
                        .Title("col3 example");
                    c.Bound(x => x.col4)
                        .Title("col4 example");
                    c.Bound(x => x.col5)
                        .Title("col5 example");
```

col2-5 are the ones in question

```
                col1 = x.col1,
                col2 = (x.col2Id.HasValue)  ? "Yes" : "No",
                col3 = (x.col3Id.HasValue) ? "Yes" : "No",
                col4 = (x.col4Id.HasValue) ? "Yes" : "No",
                col5 = (x.col5) ? "Yes" : "No"
```

ofc all the col... have different names but this way it's anon.

Edit - Tried the code in my latest project to find, client template = would always only display in those fields "Yes" in green, server template = would now display in the fields `<span style='color:green'>Yes</span>` if the field was meant to display yes and `<span style='color:red'>No</span>` if the field was meant to display no.
so both bits of codes half work and the only difference between me using them then and now is that I'm now using mvc3.

Edit 2 - In whether it's a change with the latest version of telerik or something else I don't know but the issue was resolved if I changed the client template code to be like below.

```
.ClientTemplate("<# if(Col2 == 'Yes') { #><span style='color:green'>Yes</span><# } else { #><span style='color:red'>No</span><# } #>")
```

Comment: @Myzifier the edit again does not indicate the reason for the problem. I recommend you open a forum thread in the Telerik forums and attach a sample project. I don't have anything else to add.

Comment: Would of thought that with almost 600 views that more than just 1 person would find this useful but I guess not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use either server or client templates to achieve the same (depending on the binding of your grid). Here is the server template:

```
c.Bound( x => x.col4).Template( x => 
{
%>
   <%= (x.col4.HasValue ? "<span style='color:green'>Yes</span>" : "<span style='color:red'>No</span>") %>
<%
});
```

And here is a client-side template:

```
c.Bound( x => x.col4).ClientTemplate("<# if(col4) { #><span style='color:green'>Yes</span><# } else { #><span style='color:red'>No</span><# } #>");
```

Comment: Just tried the client side template but that just changed all displayed values into Green "Yes" so seeing what I can do with the server template in case that has different results.

Comment: Server template worked perfectly but I still kept the same sort of code format since it's the same as my work colleagues. (this meant everything in the [] .HasValue ? ["<span style='color:green'>Yes</span>" : "<span style='color:red'>No</span>"] ) %>  and it replaced "Yes" : "No")            if i had 2 more rep I'd mark ur answer as useful too

Comment: Atanas, is there some way of setting row attributes when Ajax binding? e.g. to set the background color of a row.

Comment: Yes. Use the OnRowDataBound client event. It exposes e.row

Comment: @CraigFisher I hope I'm understanding this right but couldn't you just use the same code as linked above but instead of style='color it would be background-color or something and that would do the same trick? [This is for you korchev but this way craig will notice a response.]

Comment: @Myzifer that code is just modifying the HTML for a particular cell. I want to be able to set the style for the whole row.

Comment: @AtanasKorchev I've found another project where I needed to do this in but due to the way I had to setup the grid the only way I could add this code was via the client-side template but with doing so I found an issue with it which was that it would always set the field to be green Yes and wouldn't display No until I turned off the client template code, any ideas what going wrong?

Comment: @Atanas Also with another page I which I was able to do server side it would then display <span style='color:green'>Yes</span> or <span style='color:red'>No</span> on the grid but I think that might have something to do with mvc3 so any ideas?

Comment: Busy or just you don't want to answer?

Comment: I usually don't reply to obscure questions posted as comments. Try posting a new question with more details or using the Telerik forums.

Comment: They aren't obscure, it's the same code as before just with different results and with any differences explained since when I 1st used your example code I used the server template where as this time I used client template and server but when I used server template I noticed that then too I got different results but all that is mentioned in the comment and that I'm now using mvc3 which is the only real difference I'd say, plus I'm not a mind reader so if you need more details ask and I shall provide if possible.

Comment: I still think that asking questions in the comments is not the best way to proceed. I suggest you modify your question and explain what the differences are, what is the expected result and what is currently happening. I can't help without those details.

Comment: The reason I put it in comments is because it's the same exact question only this time I'm getting different results, I didn't change the code itself and it's implementation is exactly the same with the single exception being I'm now using mvc3, so I really don't see why it makes any difference in this case where I put this info since it's not a completely different question but hey ho here we go.

Comment: My answer is the same for MVC3. The API of the grid and the implementation is not different in MVC3 with this regard.

Comment: Ok the post didn't like the code not being in code `` so I put it in and now it's displaying correctly in my question

Comment: Oh yeh forgot, I think I'm also using the latest version of telerik so that's a newer version than the one I previously used and it worked with.

Comment: Please stop posting here. Open a forum thread in the Telerik forums and attach a sample project there.

Comment: As I said I can't help any further without reproducing your problem. If you want me to help you - open a forum thread in the Telerik forums and attach a sample project. If not - perhaps someone else from the SO community would be able to help.

Comment: Guess that will mean I'll never get an answer then since that would basically require me to make a brand new project to cut out certain bits of code I can't disclose just to fix a bonus feature to the project which there would be only a slim chance could even be fixed.

Comment: .ClientTemplate("<# if(Col1 == 'Yes') { #><span style='color:green'>Yes</span><# } else { #><span style='color:red'>No</span><# } #>")  gets it too work

Comment: Any idea why this change would be needed?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please clarify what works now and what the change is.

Comment: I linked it 3 comments up from this and the exact change was .ClientTemplate("<# if(col4) is now .ClientTemplate("<# if(Col1 == 'Yes') and the problem was [ @AtanasKorchev I've found another project where I needed to do this in but due to the way I had to setup the grid the only way I could add this code was via the client-side template but with doing so I found an issue with it which was that it would always set the field to be green Yes and wouldn't display No until I turned off the client template code, any ideas what going wrong? – Myzifer Mar 21 at 10:01] so now it will display yes or no

Comment: and in green and red as it was meant too

Comment: Check for any differences in the data in those columns. I presume the if statement is never true hence the else block is always executed. Of course this is a blind guess (as well as my last post to this question). For the last time I say that I cannot provide any further help without seeing a running project.

Comment: it would otherwise display yes or no on the different records but but I used the client temp w/o col1= 'Yes' then it would only ever display yes as I explained before but with that slight change I did I forced it to look at the else part of the statement and not just go yes yes yes for every record, about the running project well I've explained it would run fine without the client temp code and only when that code is implemented would it change hence why I've only linked that code and now the single change I did to it in order for it too work

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered there's a client side row bound event which can be used to modify the style of a row based on it's content.
e.g.

```
    function onGridRowDataBound(e) {
        var row = e.row;
        var dataItem = e.dataItem;

        var eligible = e.row.cells[0].innerHTML.indexOf('Not') >= 0;
        if (eligible) {
            //Set the background of the entire row
            row.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know how you could set this up to read from a bit or int field?

Comment: I've otherwise tried some other examples which I've explained/linked on here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550536/telerik-grid-row-custom-formatting-on-either-bit-int-string-field